# Phpseclib running on php5.5

Tags: phpseclib

My application used to run fine on PHP 5.4.34 on Amazon Linux server.  We upgraded to PHP 5.5.18 in order to use some of the newer libraries.  Now the phpseclib generates an error:
 Undefined offset: 5827 in /var/www/lib/ShellClient/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php on line 1073

In this app I login via Net_SSH2 and execute command another Amazon Linux server.

I start with Crypt_RSA and Net_SSH2
The following code gives notice in infinite loop:

```
$key = new \Crypt_RSA();
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents([PUBLIC_KEY]));
$ssh = new \Net_SSH2([IP_ADDRESS]], 22);
if(!$ssh->login([USERNAME]], $key)){           
    return false;               
}
$ssh->exec([COMMAND]]);
return true;
```

The error is in the BigInteger.php in function  _subtract, which is used by Net_SSH2).

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 5827 in /var/www/lib/ShellClient/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php on line 1073

```
    if ($carry) {
       for (; !$x_value[$i]; ++$i) { //1073
            $x_value[$i] = MATH_BIGINTEGER_MAX_DIGIT;
        }
    --$x_value[$i];
    }
```

Before my app ran on PHP 5.4.34 and login via NetSSH2 worked properly without any warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess: you're not running the latest version of phpseclib. The latest version is 0.3.8. The issue you're describing sounds like https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/pull/331 which has been fixed since 0.3.7.

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been fixed in phpseclib 0.3.9.